# Objective C / C. I get wrong Value when i try to get Mac Adress on IOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, c, mac-address

I'm trying to use a C code to obtain mac adress on any IOS device. 
I'm trying it on a iPhone 6 plus but it seems not work.

My output will look as follows:

2015-02-15 15:37:37.947 MyDemo[438:223963] Mac Address: 02:00:00:00:00:00

Anyone can help me for this please ?
Thanks.

This is the GetMacAdress.m
Original source code courtesy John from iOSDeveloperTips.com

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <net/if_dl.h>

...

- (NSString *)getMacAddress
{
  int                 mgmtInfoBase[6];
  char                *msgBuffer = NULL;
  size_t              length;
  unsigned char       macAddress[6];
  struct if_msghdr    *interfaceMsgStruct;
  struct sockaddr_dl  *socketStruct;
  NSString            *errorFlag = NULL;

  // Setup the management Information Base (mib)
  mgmtInfoBase[0] = CTL_NET;        // Request network subsystem
  mgmtInfoBase[1] = AF_ROUTE;       // Routing table info
  mgmtInfoBase[2] = 0;              
  mgmtInfoBase[3] = AF_LINK;        // Request link layer information
  mgmtInfoBase[4] = NET_RT_IFLIST;  // Request all configured interfaces

  // With all configured interfaces requested, get handle index
  if ((mgmtInfoBase[5] = if_nametoindex("en0")) == 0) 
    errorFlag = @"if_nametoindex failure";
  else
  {
    // Get the size of the data available (store in len)
    if (sysctl(mgmtInfoBase, 6, NULL, &length, NULL, 0) < 0) 
      errorFlag = @"sysctl mgmtInfoBase failure";
    else
    {
      // Alloc memory based on above call
      if ((msgBuffer = malloc(length)) == NULL)
        errorFlag = @"buffer allocation failure";
      else
      {
        // Get system information, store in buffer
        if (sysctl(mgmtInfoBase, 6, msgBuffer, &length, NULL, 0) < 0)
          errorFlag = @"sysctl msgBuffer failure";
      }
    }
  }

  // Befor going any further...
  if (errorFlag != NULL)
  {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorFlag);
    return errorFlag;
  }

  // Map msgbuffer to interface message structure
  interfaceMsgStruct = (struct if_msghdr *) msgBuffer;

  // Map to link-level socket structure
  socketStruct = (struct sockaddr_dl *) (interfaceMsgStruct + 1);

  // Copy link layer address data in socket structure to an array
  memcpy(&macAddress, socketStruct->sdl_data + socketStruct->sdl_nlen, 6);

  // Read from char array into a string object, into traditional Mac address format
  NSString *macAddressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", 
                                macAddress[0], macAddress[1], macAddress[2], 
                                macAddress[3], macAddress[4], macAddress[5]];
  NSLog(@"Mac Address: %@", macAddressString);

  // Release the buffer memory
  free(msgBuffer);

  return macAddressString;
}
```

Comment: I got the mac adress using the identifierForVendor method of UIDevice. 

//Getting Mac adress from device.
    UIDevice *device = [[UIDevice alloc]init];
    NSString *macAdress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device identifierForVendor]];
    NSLog(@"%@",macAdress);

But would be nice to make it work with C code. :)

Comment: That is not a MAC address on iOS7/8 but an apple generated unique identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is some pretty nasty low-level code.

I personally think that anyone who writes code of the form:

```
if ((a=b)==c)
```

...should be shot. We're not writing assembler here - Don't write code that looks like a typo to save 1 statement. (That rant is directed at the original author, not you.)

I'm not familiar enough with the low-level system functions to be able to tell what's wrong without a lot of digging.

However, stepping back from why your code isn't working, WHY do you need the MAC address? Does it have to be the actual network MAC address?

Apple no longer allows you to get that information because it allows you to uniquely track the user's device. If you do find a way to do it, your app will be rejected. (Not really Apple's fault; there was a big stink in the industry and all the device vendors had to block providing this info.)

@mad_mask's suggestion of using identifierForVendor is probably the best solution. That gives you an ID that's unique for that device for your company.

Comment: I work with iBeacon. I want to know if a device has already found in the range of my beacons. In my case identifierForVendor will work ? That key will be unique only for my  company ? if i understand for the same device, each app of my company will get the same ID but if an another company made an app, they will get an another one ? Kindly let me know. Your guidance is much appreciated. Thank You !

Comment: I'm pretty sure identifierForVendor is unique for a device for a company. So if I have 3 iOS devices, each one will report a different UUID for your apps, and yet a different set of IDs for another company's apps. Why not go read the docs on that method? That's the definitive source for answers to such questions.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to get the MAC address for an apple device any longer. This was added to prevent applications from using the MAC address as a unique identifier for tracking. It always comes out as 02:00:00:00:00:00 regardless of the route you take to finding it.

The vendor and marketing Ids you have to use instead are not the MAC address but something else.

I have written a network scanner and as far as I have been able to tell, there is no way round this unless you can talk to an external device on the same LAN segment which has visibility of the device on the network and can send it to you.

Comment: Just curious: is your scanner open source?

Comment: Sorry its not open source.